# How to add a Pie chart and grouped Bar chart on plotly express subplots

Tags: python, visualization, subplot, plotly-express

Below is the syntax used to get the pie chart and grouped bar chart ***using plotly express subplots***

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

specs = [[{'type':'pie'}, {"type": "bar"}]]
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=specs, shared_yaxes = True,subplot_titles=['Pie Chart',
                                                                                     'Grouped Bar Chart'])
                    
                    

fig.add_trace(go.Pie(
                            labels = df_pie['index'], 
                            values = df_pie['count'],
                            hole = 0.6,
                            marker_colors = ['#353837','#646665', '#8e9492', '#c9d1ce'],
                            ), 1, 1)  

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
                        x = df_bar['Satisfaction'],
                        y = df_bar['count'],
                        base  =df_bar['Gender'],
                        ),1,2)

fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, 
                  title=dict(text="Visualization",
                             font=dict(
                                        family="Arial",
                                        size=20,
                                        color='#283747')
                    ))  

fig.show()
```

and below is the results I get based on the above code,

[image]

How can I get the pie chart look like this

[image]

and the bar chart look like this
[image]

by plotly express subplots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `textinfo` for pie-chart. For bar graph, you will need to create the text you want to show on each bar and then use `text` to display it. Also, as you are looking for grouped bar plots, you will need to use create two traces and then combine then to the subplot - 1,2. Note that the `textposition=auto` will select the right way to display the text. In the case of bars, due to length, it has moved the text to be displayed vertically.

As the data was not provided, I created some basic data. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

specs = [[{'type':'pie'}, {"type": "bar"}]]
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=specs, shared_yaxes = True, subplot_titles=['Pie Chart', 'Grouped Bar Chart'])

##My data creation##                    
df_pie=pd.DataFrame({'index':[1,2,3,4], 'count':[442,459,289,280]})                    
df_bar=pd.DataFrame({'Satisfaction': ['Excellent', 'Excellent', 'Good', 'Good', 'Poor', 'Poor', 'Neutral', 'Neutral'], 'count': [442, 459, 289, 280, 442, 459, 289, 280], 'Gender': ['Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female']})                    

fig.add_trace(go.Pie(
                            labels = df_pie['index'], 
                            values = df_pie['count'],
                            hole = 0.6,
                            marker_colors = ['#353837','#646665', '#8e9492', '#c9d1ce'],
                            textinfo='percent+value',  ## ADD - display both
                            ), 1, 1)  

## New column to get percentage of row across all Male/Females
df_bar['percentage'] = df_bar.groupby(['Gender'])['count'].transform(lambda z: round(z / z.sum() * 100))

## New column - text of count and percentage - how you need the annotation shown
df_bar['Text']=df_bar['count'].astype(str) + ',' + df_bar['percentage'].astype(str)+'%'

## Create individual traces for Male and Female
trace1 = go.Bar(
    x=df_bar[df_bar.Gender == 'Male']['Satisfaction'],
    y=df_bar[df_bar.Gender == 'Male']['count'],
    name='Male',
    text=df_bar[df_bar.Gender == 'Male']['Text'], ## Display text
    textposition='auto',
)

trace2 = go.Bar(
    x=df_bar[df_bar.Gender == 'Female']['Satisfaction'],
    y=df_bar[df_bar.Gender == 'Female']['count'],
    name='Female',
    text=df_bar[df_bar.Gender == 'Male']['Text'], ## Display text
    textposition='auto'
)

fig.append_trace(trace1, 1,2) ## Add as first set of bars in second subplot
fig.append_trace(trace2,1,2) ## Add as second set of bars in second subplot

##Removed your original code
#fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
#                        x = df_bar['Satisfaction'],
#                        y = df_bar['count'],
#                        base  =df_bar['Gender'],
#                        ),1,2)

fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, 
                  title=dict(text="Visualization",
                             font=dict(
                                        family="Arial",
                                        size=20,
                                        color='#283747')
                    ))  

fig.show()
```

[image]